# Understanding Spark 1.6.3 <-> JDBC (Oracle) connection in sparklyr

Tags: r, oracle, apache-spark, jdbc, sparklyr

Using [**sparklyr**](https://spark.rstudio.com/) I access a table from Oracle via JDBC in the following manner:

```
tbl_sample_stuff <- spark_read_jdbc(
    sc = sc,
    name = "tbl_spark_some_table",
    options = list(
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//my.host.with.data:0000/my.host.service.details",
        driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        user = "MY_USERNAME",
        password = "SOME_PASSWORD",
        # dbtable = "(SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD > 10)  ALIAS"),
        dbtable = "some_table"
    ),
    memory = FALSE
)
```

The **`sample_stuff`** table is accessible. For instance running `glimpse(tbl_sample_stuff)` produces the required results.

## Questions

1. Let's say I want to derive a simple count per group using the code below:

   ```
   dta_tbl_sample_stuff_category  <- tbl_sample_stuff %>% 
       count(category_variable) %>% 
       collect()
   ```

   As a consequence my Spark 1.6.3 delivers the following job:
   [image: Spark Job]

   - What is actually going on there, why there is a one `collect` job running first for a long period of time (~ 7 mins)? My view would be that the optimal approach would initially run some SQL like `SELECT COUNT(category_variable) FROM table GROUP BY category_variable` on that data and then collected the results. It *feels* to me that this job is downloading the data first and then aggregating, is that correct?
2. What's the optimal way of using JDBC connection via [sparklyr](/questions/tagged/sparklyr). In particular, I would like to know:

   - What's wise in terms of creating temporary tables? Should I always create temporary tables for data I may want to analyse frequently?

---

## Other details

- I'm adding Oracle driver via

  ```
  configDef$sparklyr.jars.default <- ora_jar_drv
  ```
- Rest is typical connection to Spark cluster managed on Yarn returned as `sc` object to R session.